# xml saves without errors, but then has an error a few minutes later

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

This xml file I wrote saves without errors and displays exactly how I expect it to in the preview in eclipse.  But given enough time (about 5-10 minutes), after continuing to work on other parts of the project like the actual Java files, this file throws an error.

It's complaining because I'm anchoring onto a view that is declared further below in the xml file.  But I can't get around this since all 3 major parts are dependent on each other.  If I change it around, it doesn't look good at all.

How can I resolve this?

```
<!-- The chat bubble -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/chat_bubble_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

    <!-- The user's name above the chat bubble -->
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/chat_bubble_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/chat_bubble_comment"  ERROR HERE!!!!
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dip"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="Username"
        android:textColor="#88000000">
        </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chat_bubble_comment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/chat_bubble_username"            
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/chat_bubble_profile_picture" 
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_yellow"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:text="Hello bubbles!"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light" />

     <!--  The user's profile picture next to the chat bubble -->
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/chat_bubble_profile_picture"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/chat_bubble_comment"
        />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
android:layout_alignLeft="@id/chat_bubble_comment"
```

to

```
android:layout_alignLeft="=@+id/chat_bubble_comment"
```

Comment: I think `+@id/chat_bubble_comment` should `@+id/chat_bubble_comment`

Comment: @Fahim Wow I didn't know you could do that.  Should I leave all the id attributes the way they are (with the plus signs)? I'm not entirely sure how the plus sign works now (you kind of just flipped my world). 
I also needed to do this for the `layout_toRightOf` attribute in the middle element. I'll accept this answer if it doesn't randomly decide to throw an error within the next 15 minutes or so.

Comment: wherever u have use just @id/, change it to @+id/

Comment: @Fahim This explains it: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html
The first time I use an id, I have to create it with the plus sign.  Every time I use the id after that I can go ahead and leave out the plus sign since I'm just referencing it and not creating it. So I should take out the plus signs in the id attributes for the 2nd and 3rd element.